# Inequality with discriminants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, quadratics

> If $x^2-ax+1-2a^2>0$ for all $x \in {R}$,
> find range of $a$

The solution to this takes the discriminant of the expression in terms of $a$, i.e.,
$$\implies D={a^2-4(1-2a)}>0(\because x \in R)$$ and then figures out the range from the inequality in $a$.

But what I dont understand is, as per my knowledge, the discriminant is taken from a quadratic equation, so in order for $D$ to be as it is in the solution, we must first consider $$x^2-ax+1-2a^2=0$$

What I mean to say is,

Say $x^2-ax+1-2a^2=y$

$$\implies x^2-ax+1-2a^2-y=0$$
$$D=a^2-4(1-2a^2-y)>0$$

But the solution has considered only $a^2-4(1-2a^2-y)>0$, which means that they have considered $y=0$, but the question says that $y>0$.

The question is clearly stating that the *expression is greater than and not equal to $0$.* So how can we work with the discriminant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already a few solutions provided, but I believe I can offer a succinct explanation for the pre-calculus level. This is how I am taught in the Singapore O-level additional mathematics syllabus

Recall that for a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, descriminant = $b^2-4ac$

when discriminant $> 0$, the equation has 2 real and distinct roots

when discriminant $= 0$, the equation has 2 real roots that are of the same magnitude

when discriminant $<0$, the equation has 2 complex roots

Given $x^2−ax+1−2a^2>0$, $x^2−ax+1−2a^2=0$ has no real solutions. Why? Well, if the expression given is always more than $0$, then it will never equal $0$, so it cannot have any roots.

Since $x^2−ax+1−2a^2=0$ has no real solutions, so discriminant $<0$, or

$$a^2-4(1)(1-2a^2)<0$$
$$a^2-4+8a^2<0$$
$$9a^2-4<0$$
$$(3a-2)(3a+2)<0$$
Sketching the graph, we get $-2/3<a<2/3$

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the question is the following: find all $a$'s such that the inequality
$x^2-ax+1-2a^2>0$
holds for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Now you look at the polynomial in $x$ above ( $a$ is a parameter) and you impose the condition that the discriminant is negative. That [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Discriminant%5Bx%5E2-ax%2B1-2a%5E2%2C%20x%5D)
$$D_a=9 a^2 - 4 <0$$

Comment: But, I have learnt that if an equation is
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
then $D=b^2-4ac$.

Where is the given expression equating with $0$ here? Is my understanding of discriminants incorrect?

Also, what do you mean by "you impose the condition that the discriminant is negative. "?

Comment: @Altercating Current: in your above equation, $a$, $b$, $c$ are better thought of as placeholders. They can be : whatever is in front of $x^2$, $x$, and free term.

Answer (score 0):

For very (very, **very**) large $|x|$, $$x^2-ax+1-2a^2\approx x^2>0$$  This may be hard to see — how large $|x|$ needs to be depends on $a$.  But for any fixed value of $a$ there is some point beyond which the $x^2$ term dominates.

What about for small $|x|$?  In particular, choose $x$ to make $x^2-ax+1-2a^2$ as small as possible, and call the chosen $x$-value $x_0$.  There are two possibilities:

- If $$x_0^2-ax_0+1-2a^2\geq0$$ then for every other value of $x$ $$x^2-ax+1-2a^2\geq x_0^2-ax_0+1-2a^2\geq0$$
- If $x_0^2-ax_0+1-2a^2<0$, then as $x$ ranges between $x_0$ and very large (or very small) values, there is some intermediate point where $$x^2-ax+1-2a^2=0$$

Thus the inequality in the problem fails iff $x^2-ax+1-2a^2=0$ has at two solutions — one between $-\infty$ and $x_0$ and one between $x_0$ and $\infty$.  The discriminant helps you answer that equivalent question.

Comment: Please check the edits I made in the post to actually state where my confusion lies in the discriminant part